# AirWatch MDM with Xamarin ipa

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mdm, airwatch

We are currently adding some mobile applications built using Xamarin.iOS to our AirWatch MDM entreprise store. Unfortunately it doesn't behave as it should: we trigger the download on the device, it downloads the app but it doesn't install on the device. We checked the device logs and we seem to have an issue with profile or code signing.

Have other persons already used Xamarin.iOS with AirWatch MDM?
If yes, then how do you build your ipa file? Currently we build them for armv7+armv7s, with all assemblies linked, using LLVM and we build using AppStore mode.

When we build the app in AdHoc mode with UDIDs in the provisioning profile and add it through iTunes then it is installing and running fine.
Maybe it is necessary to go the AdHoc way, with this ipa file, with all UDIDs referenced, or, we should go the InHouse way? https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used AirWatch but I do currently use the Enterprise program (with ad-hoc builds) for internal company apps. I had the same issue when I tried using the wrong provisioning profile when signing the application.

Comment: With an enterprise program, if you do InHouse builds, do you still need to have the UDIDs in the provisioning profile?

Comment: No. Only development certs/profiles need the UDID. Enterprise apps are signed by the publisher (you).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have been using Xamarin with Airwatch for two years.  I have no problem deploying applications to the field.  I routinely provide updates for the programs and in most cases they are 100% deployed in a matter of a couple of days.  The majority of the last forced deployment completed in less than 8 hours.

It sounds like it might be the way you are uploading the application into Airwatch.  Are you requiring something that is not on the user's device such as a passcode?

I have about 240 IOS devices deployed with a mixture of OS (6.0 - 8). I do not build the apps for the AppStore.  I can see where that could be an issue with the deployment methodology.  When you deploy via IPA in Airwatch, it is assuming you are deploying enterprise applications.  When I deploy an AppStore program I use the catalog and they install via the AppStore.

Our IPA's work either via iTunes or through Airwatch.  Let me know if I can be of any further assistance.